# Can I play Grand Theft Auto V offline on Xbox One S?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I have "Xbox One S All-Digital Edition" console. I want to play GTA V completely offline once I download the full game from Xbox store. While looking for this, I found some unclear answers stating, I can play offline but I need to be connected to the internet EVERY time I start the game(Perhaps while logging-in to the console). Is it true?

I have downloaded gears of war 4, Halo 5 and Forza Horizon 4 which I can play **completely offline**. These games don't require the internet even while logging in to the console. Is this the same for GTA V too?

P.S: Link to the game on Xbox store would be really helpful.

Comment: Here is the [Microsoft store link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/grand-theft-auto-v/bpj686w6s0nh) for it, which should be similar if not the same as the Xbox Store.  Doesn't look very useful though.

Comment: Thanks Timmy Jim for the link, Can I play this completely offline?

Comment: You could play it on the 360 and Xbox One offline. I don't expect this to be different

Comment: He's correct in saying there's a lot of dissenting opinions. I can find plenty of posts on forums stating "Of course, duh" but also plenty of people saying they can't. If someone's going to answer they should probably check firsthand.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with Venoda. I am expecting response from someone who has already installed and tried playing it offline.

Comment: I downloaded the whole game which is around 69 GB. Now I am able to play offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "you need the be online" thing was very confusing at the beginning. I'm using and Xbox One X and Xbox 360 and I can play GTA V offline on both of them.

You don't have to connect to the Internet when you buy the game. I believe the game license itself downloads with the game.

But if you're planning to play through Xbox Game Pass or if you bought the game free from "Xbox Live Gold Games", the console might need to check if you're still subscribed to Game Pass or Xbox Live.

Comment: My console is Digital edition. Hence, some people assumed(they didn't experiment either)  that Xbox might need the internet connection to check the game license periodically with the Xbox server.  I presume that you're using Xbox console that supports physical disk; in which case you might not need the internet connection to check the license as the disk itself proves the license authenticity.

Comment: Imm sorry, I don't have any knowledge about Digital Edition. You should ask Microsoft support itself if you need proper answer.

Comment: The dudes in the Microsoft community are also not clear about the internals of this situation. Anyway, your answer makes sense, I wanted to upvote but I don't have enough reputation points. I need to buy the game and see to mark your response as the correct answer.

Comment: Don't ask community. Ask directly to Xbox Support and get them an answer not just on phone or chat but e-mail. If you encounter any issues, you will have a document on your hand.

Comment: That's a good idea. I can directly e-mail to Xbox support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can play the game offline, but you can not save it with out signing in, so you have to connect to the internet either way.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about how you got to this answer? Is this your personal experience, did you find any documentation specifying the behaviour you described?